# What is the derivative of $f(x)=e^{f^{\prime \prime}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I made this problem:

$f(x)=e^{f^{\prime \prime}}$

I have just been taught the first derivative, and was thinking about what if the derivative depended upon it own derivative.  I understand that $e^x$ is its "own" derivative, but the problem I made I was thinking that the first derviative is not logical, because to know the first derivative you then must know the 2nd or 3rd derviative, it seems self-referenecing.

Is the problem I made, a real problem or just some abstract idea?

Comment: Do you mean to solve for $f$ since you have $f$ on both sides?

Comment: I just edited the question to be more clear. I hope its more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such kind of problems usually ask for the function $f$ itself (of course, then its derivative can be calculated, too).

And, such is called a [Differential equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_equation).

Comment: Thanks, I do not know many math terms, so it is polite when I am told math terms.

Comment: Specifically, it's a second-order, nonlinear, ordinary differential equation. In general, it is not always possible to solve these (solve means find $f(x)$ such that $f(x)=e^{f''(x)}$). I thought solving this would clarify your question, but I could only get so far. If $y=f(x)$ then I got $y'=2ylny-2y-C_1$ but that's where I got stuck. Maybe wiser minds than mine can finish it (or do it right from the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{d}{dx} [f(x)] = \frac{d}{dx}\exp (f''(x))$ and by the chain rule its derivative is
$\frac{d}{dx}f''(x) \times \frac{d}{d(f''(x))} \exp(f''(x)) = f'''(x) \times \exp(f''(x))$

Comment: but how can you have something depend upon its own 3rd derivative?

Comment: Since you use $f$ in the answer, you could also simply say $f'(x)$.

Comment: That happens when the function depends on its second derivative